# Translating the picklist values in salesforce used in wrapper class

Tags: apex, picklist

I have a picklist field on a custom object who's values are translated using translation workbench.
In my class I am using wrapper class and displaying the picklist value on a visualforce page using "output:text component".But the translated valu is not getting rendered as I have used a wrapper class.Can any one help to find a way around for this  issue.

Comment: Why don't you just display the picklist?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a SOQL function `toLabel()` to get translated picklist values when you query the data:

```
SELECT toLabel(your_field__c) FROM YourObject__c
```

See also http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm

Comment: Thanks Guy the solution did worked.

Now when i am converting the picklist to checkboxes and display it on VF page it does not render the translated values insted the english values are displayed.In the query I have used toLabel.
Any clues on this?

Comment: That really depends on what the VF code looks like.. Can you post it (maybe in a new question which you reference here)